# Does Virtuoso support OWL Full reasoning?

Tags: rdf, sparql, owl, virtuoso, reasoning

I read a tutorial in  [Inference Rules & Reasoning](http://docs.openlinksw.com/virtuoso/rdfsparqlrule.html#rdfsameas) for Virtuoso. In the example 16.14.9 they mentioned the following:

```
SQL>ttlp ('
  <john1> a <person> .
  <john2> a <person> .
  <mary> a <person> .
  <mike> a <person> .
  <john1> <name> "John" .
  <john2> <name> "John" .
  <john1> <address> "101 A street" .
  <john2> <address> "102 B street" .
  <john2> <knows> <mike> .
  <john1> <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#sameAs> <john2> .
  <mary> <knows> "John" .
  <mike> <knows> <john1> .
  <mike> <knows> <john2> .
  <john1> <name> "Tarzan" .
  <mike> <nam> "Tarzan" .
  ', '', 'ifps');


  SQL>ttlp ('
  <name> a <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#InverseFunctionalProperty> .
  <name> <http://www.openlinksw.com/schemas/virtrdf#nullIFPValue> "Tarzan" .
  ', '', 'ifp_list');

  SQL>rdfs_rule_set ('ifps', 'ifp_list');

  SQL>SPARQL define input:inference "ifps"  SELECT * FROM <ifps> WHERE {<john1> ?p ?o};

  p                                                                                 o
  VARCHAR                                                                           VARCHAR
  _______________________________________________________________________________

  address                                                                           101 A street
  name                                                                              John
  http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#sameAs                                              john2
  http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type                                   person
  name                                                                              Tarzan
  name                                                                              John
  knows                                                                             mike
  http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type                                   person
  address                                                                           102 B street
```

As we can see, owl:InverseFunctionalProperty used by datatype property `<name>`, does that mean OWL Full reasoning can be used in Virtuoso?
In this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21487939/what-is-the-difference-between-datatypeproperty-objectproperty-functionalpro), the first answer was talking the problem of using OWL Full reasoning with datatype property.

Answer (score 0):

Based on their docs, it seems like they do support InverseFunctionalProperty, but they surely don't support OWL Full; it's undecidable.

Comment: support InverseFunctionalProperty for data-type property is making problems in consistency, Am I right?